# Does kotlin short circuit list evalutation?

Tags: list, kotlin

Does Kotlin evaluate all objects in a list when running `list.all()` or `list.any()` functions. For example:

```
val myList = listOf(1, 8, 11, 13, 15)
val allOdd = myList.all { it % 2 == 1 }
```

Will Kotlin evaluate element 2 and beyond?

Obviously, this doesn't make a big difference in this example, but given a list of functions to evaluate, this may have a significant impact.

Comment: Just to clarify some terms: this is [_short circuiting_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), not [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). The evaluation is immediate (eager), but will stop early if a counterexample is found. Lazily evaluation would be if the list wasn't iterated at all, until some other code tried reading the value of `allOdd` (only then would it do the iteration), such that if the value is never read, no iteration is ever done at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/d0452d569fd2fa557ecd3479b6bd8694adeed049/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L1727) for `all`, once it finds an element of the list that does not match the predicate, it returns immediately and does not continue to evaluate the rest of the elements:

```kotlin
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.all(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean {
    if (this is Collection && isEmpty()) return true
    for (element in this) if (!predicate(element)) return false
    return true
}
```

Similar case to [any](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/d0452d569fd2fa557ecd3479b6bd8694adeed049/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L1748).

---

This could be tested with the following code:

```kotlin
var evaluatedLastItem = false
val list = listOf(
    { true },
    { false },
    {
        evaluatedLastItem = true
        false
    }
)
val allTrue = list.all { it() == true }

println("allTrue = $allTrue")
println("evaluatedLastItem = $evaluatedLastItem")
```

Output:

```
allTrue = false
evaluatedLastItem = false
```

Comment: Would be nice if this was specified behaviour rather than empirically determined.

Comment: @muistooshort Agreed. Kotlin's stdlib documentation is clear and accurate as far as it goes, but omits far too much important info; this is just one example. AISI, if you ever need to look at the code, then the documentation has failed. (Especially as the code is subject to change in future versions, so we can't tell which behaviour can be relied on. I would _expect_ that short-circuiting is intended to be part of the contract here, but who can be sure?) Perhaps we've been spoiled by Java's excellent and exemplary documentation…